# A cell has two data points combined, separated by a space. How to separate into 2 different cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a ton of data points (~70k rows of 1 column). I'm trying to clean the data because each row actually has two data points, separated by a space in the middle. I'm trying to separate them to form another column, side by side to the existing one. How can I do this? I've played around with LEFT, RIGHT, MID, etc and can't get anything to work.

So, for example, the first data in the sample shown below I would like to have 2 columns. One with a 4 and one with a 0, etc.

Note: The remaining data isn't consistent as to what is shown, so is there a way to simply separate the data point after the space?

[image]

Comment: Is this a one-time problem, so you need to fix it only once, or will you be getting more text values that are two values separated by a space. P.S. Look at the ```FIND``` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Data` -> `Text to columns`

It will open a wizard to guide you step by step, In Delimeters choose `Space`

[image]

Go `Next`and check the final result, you can even select on each resulting column idf the data is text, datetime, etc.

[image]